# Special double precision value 64bit

Tags: double, 32bit-64bit

While I am aware of the 64bit special notice on round-tripping on the MSDN site (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfsatb94(v=vs.110).aspx), I have a number that seems to be quite special under that umbrella.

A double of value -0.21943 round-trips as "-0.21943" in 32 bit libraries, but it as "-0.21942999999999999" in 64 bit mode, using "R" or "G17". Only if unformatted does it come out "-0.21943".

The best part is, the 2 string values "-0.21943" and "-0.21942999999999999" both seem to work identically and look to be synonymous. This says TRUE in either 32 or 64 bit mode:

```
double fiveDecimals = double.Parse("-0.21943");
double seventeenDecimals = double.Parse("-0.21942999999999999");

Console.WriteLine("Five with no formatting: {0}", fiveDecimals);
Console.WriteLine("Five with Roundtrip formatting: {0}", fiveDecimals.ToString("R"));

Console.WriteLine("Seventeen with no formatting: {0}", seventeenDecimals);
Console.WriteLine("Seventeen with Roundtrip formatting: {0}", seventeenDecimals.ToString("R"));

Console.WriteLine(fiveDecimals == seventeenDecimals);
```

32 bit results:

```
Five with no formatting: -0.21943
Five with Round-trip formatting: -0.21943
Seventeen with no formatting: -0.21943
Seventeen with Round-trip formatting: -0.21943
True
```

64 bit results:

```
Five with no formatting: -0.21943
Five with Round-trip formatting: -0.21942999999999999
Seventeen with no formatting: -0.21943
Seventeen with Round-trip formatting: -0.21942999999999999
True
```

Can anyone help explain why this 5 decimal place number would be affected by this known 64 bit difference?

Comment: The actual value of the closest double to -0.21943 is -0.2194299999999999861710620052690501324832439422607421875. Different display methods show different numbers of digits.

Comment: How does it happen then that no formatting gets you just the original 5 digits? Why isn't "-0.2194299999999999861710620052690501324832439422607421875" what you get for the no format specified version?

Comment: There is an infinite set of decimal fractions that would round to -0.2194299999999999861710620052690501324832439422607421875 on conversion to double. The shortest one of them is -0.21943, so that is the preferred result for some conversion methods. If you want more detail on the conversion rules you will have to add a tag to get experts on the programming language you are using.

Comment: I could add code tags, but we see it in both our .Net and our Linux 64bit apps that the round-trip value is the long one and so it seemed more IEEE on 64bit related than specific language question.

So far I have only tested .Net 32bit, but that round-trip formats as "-0.21943" which seems odd since it is the same IEEE double no matter the executable bit target is it not?

Comment: Yes, you should always be getting -0.2194299999999999861710620052690501324832439422607421875, except possibly as an intermediate result during calculations. The difference is the highly language and context dependent matter of display format.